# Spring MVC with Tomcat UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, character-encoding, tomcat9

At the moment I'm trying to get started with Spring MVC.
Something wrong with my encoding.

Every time response header is:
`Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1`, so all non-ASCII characters appear as `?`.

Also I try not to use any config files, all config is programmly

I tried:

1. Add `CharacterEncodingFilter` in my `ConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`

```
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
   //if encoding has issues we need to add UTF-8 encoding filter
   CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
   encodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
   encodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
   //encoding filter must be the first one
   return new Filter[]{encodingFilter,
       new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"),
    };
}
```

In my `WebMvcConfigurer`:
2. configure message converter

```
@Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
```

3. add message converter bean

```
 @Bean
    public StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
```

4. setup thymeleaf ViewResolver's encoding

```
resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

In my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`
5. add encoding filter

```
http.addFilterBefore(new CharacterEncodingFilter("UTF-8", true, true), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
```

I also tried add VM option `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in my tomcat run configuration

Nothing works for me, responce header charset is `ISO-8859-1`

All files encoding is `UTF-8`, Intellij Idea option "Default encoding for options file" also is `UTF-8`
maven compiler encoding property:
`<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`
All my html files has this meta tag line for encoding.
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

tomcat version is 9.0.74, JDK is v11, spring version 5.3.27

Answer (score 0):

Solved it
Solution is set thymeleaf's content type

```
@Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
```